# Cannot find PHP type in Data Format

Tags: input-formats

I am new to Drupal and using Drupal7.23 in windows7 with XAMPP installed. While I am creating any content I cannot find "PHP type" in the Data Formats. Kindly tell how to add PHP type in Data Format, as I need to add PHP to the content.

Comment: You need to enable `PHP Filter` module available in core!!

Comment: If you plan to write PHP, please create your code in custom modules or your theme. Don't inject it into data items - it's a very bad idea. You can easily create security holes or break pages and it can be a nightmare to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the 'PHP Filter' module available in drupal core:

Go to modules list: `/admin/modules` and than in Core you will find PHP filter module as indicated below, so just enable it.

[image]